# Printing code coverage status on pull request for Bitbucket stash based repository using JenkinsFile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-pipelines

I currently have a private Bitbucket stash repository e.g. https://xyzgit.company.com/stash/scm/proj1/subproj2.

This is a gradle based project which uses JenkinsFile to manage different stages for Jenkins Job (including setup, build, publish etc). Whenever a new change is committed to a branch, it automatically triggers a build or provide an option to trigger a build. To analyse code coverage, we use Jcoco Plugin which analyzes all subfolders to get the coverage.

My current requirement is to print code coverage status on the pull request after the build is successful over jenkins using JenkinsFile.

I came across a plugin i.e. [Bit Bucket Code Coverage Plugin](https://github.com/adiesner/bitbucket-pr-coverage-status-plugin) but I did not find any such plugin available to be installed in my Jenkins Environment. I tried to do it manually but it redirects me to plugin available for Github.

I anyway installed that and tried what is suggested in the document i.e. adding these two lines in my Jenkins File :

```
step([$class: 'MasterCoverageAction', scmVars: [GIT_URL: "https://xyzgit.company.com/stash/scm/proj1/subproj2"]])
step([$class: 'CompareCoverageAction', scmVars: [GIT_URL: "https://xyzgit.company.com/stash/scm/proj1/subproj2"]])
```

It did not work. I got the following Error :

```
[GitHub PR Status] Attempt to discover PR for null @ null
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // wrap
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // wrap
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.github.com/repos/stash/scm
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0
(HttpURLConnection.java:1872) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.
HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.
getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:602)
Caused: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
https://api.github.com/repos/stash/scm
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.
newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.
newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.
run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.
run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.
getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.
getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.
getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.
getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:612)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:594)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:272)
Caused: org.kohsuke.github.GHFileNotFoundException: {"message":"Not 
Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.handleApiError(Requester.java:686)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:293)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:234)
at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getRepository(GitHub.java:443)
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.
GitHubPullRequestRepository.getGitHubRepository
(GitHubPullRequestRepository.java:57)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Could not retrieve GitHub repository named 
stash/scm (Do you have properly set 'GitHub project' field in job 
configuration?) at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.
GitHubPullRequestRepository.getGitHubRepository  
(GitHubPullRequestRepository.java:59) at 
com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.
GitHubPullRequestRepository.getPullRequestFor
(GitHubPullRequestRepository.java:32)
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.
PrIdAndUrlUtils.getMultiBranch(PrIdAndUrlUtils.java:63)
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.
PrIdAndUrlUtils.getPrId(PrIdAndUrlUtils.java:72)
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.
CompareCoverageAction.perform(CompareCoverageAction.java:93)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.
CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.
CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.
SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.
call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.
SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.
run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.
runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.
run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anybody help me if any additional setting is there? or How to inject env `CHANGE_URL` and `CHANGE_ID` in JenkinsFile ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Code Coverage Plugin for Bitbucket Server](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bitbucket.code-coverage-plugin/server/overview). In it's repo you could find [maven-based client](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-code-coverage/src/master/code-coverage-maven-plugin/) which supports JACOCO and could be easily called from gradle.